# Mishnah Berurah on Torah Study

Tags: halacha, mishnah-berurah

The Mishnah Berurah (155:3) states that a person is obligated on a daily basis to study written Torah, which consists of Tanach and oral Torah, which consists of Mishnah, Gemara, Poskim (i.e. books of halacha) and Mussar (Mishnah Berurah 1:12)

Does one fulfill his obligation to learn mishnayos by learning gemara, since gemara has mishnayos in it?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96914/170

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch YD 246, 4 (quoted from Rambam Mada Hilchot Talmud Tora 1, 11-12) :

> חייב אדם לשלש למודו
>   1. 
>   שליש בתורה שבכתב דהיינו הארבעה ועשרים
>
> A man must divide his study in three  parts,  one third part for scriptural Tora,  i. e.  the 24 books of Tanach.
>
> 2
>   . שליש במשנה דהיינו תורה שבעל פה ופי' תורה שבכתב בלל זה ‏
>
> one third part for Mishna i. e.  **oral law and explanations of scriptural law.**
>
> 3. שליש בתלמוד דהיינו  **שיבין וישכיל אחרית דבר מראשיתו ויוציא דבר מתוך דבר וידמה דבר לדבר וידון במדות שהתורה נדרשת בהם**  עד שידע היאך עיקר המצות והיאך יוצא האסור והמותר וכיוצא בזה דברים שלמד מפי השמועה
>
> one third part for Talmud i. e.  **to deduct consequences from causes,  to learn things one from another, to compare different things,  to know how work the  thirteen rules of drashot hatora,**  to know how something was  prohibited or permitted,  and additional things learned from transmission of the Tora.
>
> 4. כיצד היה בעל אומנות ועוסק במלאכתו ג' שעות ביום וט' בתורה קורא ג' מהם בתורה שבכתב ובג' תורה שבעל פה ובג' יבין דבר מתוך דבר
>
> Practically if he works 3 hours per day,  and is involved with  Tora 9 hours,  he reads 3 hours scriptural Tora,  3 hours oral law,  and 3 hours for deductive activities.
>
> 5. במה דברים אמורים בתחילת לימודו של אדם אבל כשיגדיל בתורה ולא יהא צריך ללמוד תורה שבכתב ולא לעסוק תמיד בתורה שבעל פה יקרא בעתים מזומנים תורה שבכתב ודברי תורה שבעל פה כדי שלא ישכח דבר מדיני התורה ויפנה כל ימיו לתלמוד בלבד לפי רוחב לבו וישוב דעתו:‏
>
> The above division is for a beginner,  when he grown,  he has not to read scriptures and oral laws every day,   it's enough from time to time  to read them only to not forget them and to dedicate his days to Talmud according to his  capacities<sup>(1)</sup>.
>
> 6. הגה: וי"א שבתלמוד בבלי שהוא בלול במקרא במשנה וגמרא אדם יוצא ידי חובתו בשביל הכל (טור בשם ר"ת וע"פ ע"ל סי' רמ"ה ס"ו) ...:‏
>
> Some take the  view that learning Talmud of Babylon which is agglomerated from scriptures,  Mishna and Talmud,  a man is quite for each of the three third parties (Tur in name of Rabenu Tam...)

#### Conclusion

We see in the words of the Rambam  that Mishna and Talmud are  more **a kind of learning activity than the name of the book** which you are studying.  So,  to gain knowledge through Talmud study has not necessarily a dimension of Talmud  learning<sup>(2)</sup> until you get deep in understanding and clarifying,  if the result is to reach knowledge of what is written in the book.

Rabenu Tam however thinks that it's not necessary to make a formal separation between the three parts,  one may make all through Talmud of Babylon study.

But everyone agrees that learning a Masechet in Talmud Bavli,  the Mishna part is included because of the order necessary to know  what is written and understanding and deducting.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>The **Shlah** in the part of the book called Masechet Shavuot suggested that one learn  endlessly **mishnayot with Bartenura and Rambam's comments is Mishna and Gemara together,**  because they explain the right understanding of the mishna according to conclusions of Gemara and the psak Halacha.  (I assume that he did  not yet know the Tosfot Yom Tov,  who is +/- contemporaneous). I will give an exact quote below.  Anyway,  it seems that he see limud hatalmud as understanding the Mishna and to reach the Halacha results from Mishna and Gemara together.

> ולעולם הוי רץ למשנה יותר מן התלמוד ומכל שכן האידנא שזכירו לפירוש הרמב"ם והרב ברטנור"ה שמבארים המשנה כפי ההסכמה שבתלמוד וגם כתבו פסק ההלכה הרי  מעלת המשנה רבה כי מה שאמרו תחילה תלמוד אין לך מידה גדולה הימנו כי גירסת המשנה בלא תלמוד לא יגיעהו לתכלית  המכוון ללמד חוק ומשפט בישראל שאם לא ידע טעמי הדבר פעמים ידמה דבר לשאינו דומה ויורה הוראות טעות ועל זה אמרו במסכת סוטה פרק ג' תנאים מבלי עולם הן וכי במבלי עולם הן והלא מיושבי עולם הן שנאמר הליכות עולם לו אלא שמורין הלכה מתוך משנתן עד כאן. אבל עתה בפירוש הרמב"ם והרב ברטנורה מתוקן הכל. על כן רוב העסקו יהיה במשניות ללמוד ולחזור אותם בלי ערך ובלי הפסק

<sup>(2)</sup> Someone argued that I wrote my own conclusion instead the conclusion of the quotes. If it is not the intent of the Rambam, it is the conclusion of the commentary **Avodat Hamelech** after learning the Rambam. The source is a **Rashi in Succa 28b,** who explained **the word Talmud** (Gemara after the censorship):

> גמרא. זו היא סברא שהיו התנאים אחרונים מדקדקים בדברי הראשונים הסתומים לפרשם וליתן בהן טעם כמו שעשו האמוראים אחר התנאים שפירשו דברי התנאים שלפניהן וקבעו בהן גמרא ואותו דיוק שבימי התנאי' נקרא הש''ס: ‏
>
> Rashi: This is reasoning, when the last tanayim were deducting from the former tanayim words, which were tight, and were explain them, to give a sense, as made Amorayim who explained the sentences of the tanayim who was before them, and this deduction which is known from the tanayim period is called Talmud.

And **Rashi in Berachot 5a:**

> זה גמרא. סברת טעמי המשניות שממנו יוצאה הוראה.‏
>
> Rashi: This is Gemara (Talmud), to understand the reasoning under the mishna, from which ensue the Halacha.

See also [Beur Hagra on Shulchan Aruch note number 14](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6714) which give a proof from the Gemara in Kiddushin 49b (this need a whole explanation, I skipped it).

We see that a some activities with the book called Talmud are closer to the so called Mishna activity than to Talmud activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49579/discussion-between-kouty-and-mevaqesh).

Comment: `Someone argued that I wrote my own conclusion instead the conclusion of the quotes. If it is not the intent of the Rambam, it is the conclusion of the commentary Avodat Hamelech` No I didn't. I claimed that you didn't explain how the quotes demonstrated your claims. A flaw that remains to a degree. | Nothing in the AHM demonstrates that studying the Babylonian Talmud satisfies the requirement to learn Mishna daily. | `We see that a some activities with the book called Talmud are closer to the so called Mishna activity than to Talmud activity.` How do we see this?

Comment: The Tosofos in Kiddushin explicitly states the opinion that you fulfill all three by learning Talmud

Comment: It is rabenu Tam on the 2th chapter of sanhédrin, about Babel, belula bemikra, belula bemishna, belula betalmud

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that if one learns a Mishna in Gemara then he has fulfilled the obligation to learn Mishniyot. If the portion of Gemara he is learning does not contain/quote the/a actual Mishna then he has not fulfilled the obligation.