# Why Torah Study and Mussar Study are brought in different places in Mishnah Berurah

Tags: halacha, mishnah-berurah

The *[Mishnah Berurah 155](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.155.3?with=all&lang=bi)* in volume 2 discusses which parts of *Torah* a yeshiva student and a layman should study/ learn:

> "**ללמוד -** חייב אדם ללמוד בכל יום תורה שבכתב שהוא תנ"ך ומשנה וגמרא ופוסקים ובעלי בתים שאינם לומדים רק ג' או ד' שעות ביום לא ילמדו בגמרא לחוד דבזה אינו יוצא אלא צריך שילמוד דוקא גם ספרי פוסקים כל אחד כפי השגתו [שו"ע יו"ד וש"ך שם]: "

In [volume 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.1.12?with=all&lang=bi) it discusses the importance of learning *mussar* every day:

> "וצריך האדם לקבוע לו עת ללמוד ספרי מוסר בכל יום ויום, אם מעט ואם הרבה, כי הגדול מחבירו יצרו גדול הימנו. ותבלין היצר הרע הוא תוכחת מאמרי חז"ל. "

Why does Mishnah Berurah put the emphasis of learning *mussar* in volume 1 and discuss Torah study in volume 2, rather than discussing learning *mussar* in volume 2?

Comment: The Mishnah Berurah is a commentary on Shulchan Aruch. It makes sense in context for him to focus more on Limud Hatorah in Volume 2 when he is commenting on the piece in the Sh"A that speaks about establishing times to learn Torah. Also, your source in Volume 1 does mention the importance of Limud Hatoah, and at the end he mentions that one should also learn Sifrei Mussar (which is also Limud Torah, just a more 'focused' Limud Torah), which fits in context with the greater theme of that Siman in Sh"A, which is dealing with more 'abstract' issues that are generally addressed by Sifrei Mussar.

Comment: Look at his hakdama,where be puts a lot of emphasis on learning halacha ,since HaShem loves halacha(Berachos 8)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77890/170

Answer (score 3):

In both of the two cases you mention, the content of the Mishnah Berurah is not original content. In each case he is quoting earlier commentaries. In 1:12, the point about learning mussar originally comes from the Birchei Yosef, and is also quoted in the Sha'arei Teshuva.

**[Birchei Yosef O.C. 1:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7626&st=&pgnum=9)**

> אמנם ראוי לכל ת"ח שיקבע עת כפעם בפעם ללמוד בספרי מוסר כי כל הגדול מחבירו יצרו גדול  ואיידי דטריד בגופי הלכות ומחדש בטובו חידושי תורה קרוב שיגבה לבו וכיוצא וקבלתי כי בכלל משז"ל דתורה תבלין ליצה"ר הוא תוכחת מוסר מרז"ל קמאי ובתראי

**[Sha'arei Teshuva O.C. 1:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x339)**

> ובברכי יוסף כתב שראוי לקבוע עת ללמוד בספרי מוסר כי כל הגדול כו' וקבלתי כי תבלין היצה"ר הוא תוכחת מוסר מאמרי חז"ל

So the Mishnah Berurah mentioned it here because the earlier commentaries mentioned it here. Now you might then ask why the earlier commentaries mentioned it here, especially considering that it doesn't seem very relevant to the text of the Shulchan Aruch here which states that it is better to recite fewer supplications with proper intent than more supplications without proper intent. However, if you trace the comment back to the Birchei Yosef, you will notice that it is actually a comment on the *next* statement of the Shulchan Aruch, where it lists various parts of the Torah that are good to say every day. Commenting on *that* the Birchei Yosef adds that it's also good to learn a bit of mussar every day.

When it comes to the Mishnah Berurah in 155:3, though, he doesn't quote this statement about learning mussar because it doesn't fit the context of the discussion there. The Shulchan Aruch there is setting out the idea of there being a basic obligation to learn a certain discrete amount of Torah every day. In explaining that obligation the Mishnah Berurah turns to Yoreh Deiah siman 246, where the obligation of daily Torah study is explained. His comment in 155:3 is basically a paraphrase of the comment of the Shach in Yoreh Deiah there, which itself is a quote of the Derisha's comment to the Tur there.

**[Shach Y.D. 246:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6714)**

> כתב הדרישה יש בעלי בתים נוהגים ללמוד בכל יום גפ"ת ולא שאר פוסקים ומביאים ראיה מהא דאמרינן סוף (נדרים) [נדה] תנא דבי אליהו כל השונה הלכות בכל יום מובטח לו שהוא בן עולם הבא אבל ל"נ שיש ללמוד ספרי הפוסקים דיני התורה כמו הרי"ף ומרדכי והרא"ש ודומיהן דזהו שורש ועיקר לתורתנו ואינם יוצאים כלל בלימוד גמפ"ת דהא דתנא דבי אליהו כו' כבר כתב רש"י שם השונה הלכות פירוש הלכות פסוקות ומ"ש ר"ת כאן ש"ס בבלי בלול כו' קאי אמש"כ לפני זה אלימוד ט' שעות ביום דכיון שיש לו פנאי גדול ילמוד בש"ס אבל הנך בעלי בתים שאינם לומדים רק ג' או ד' שעות לא ילמדו בש"ס לחוד כנ"ל ע"כ

**[Derisha Y.D. 246:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6223)**

> יש בעלי בתים נוהגין ללמוד בכל יום גפ"ת ולא שאר פוסקים ומביאים ראיה מהא דאמרינן סוף פרק בתרא דנדרים תנא דבי אליהו כל השונה הלכות בכל יום מובטח לו שהוא בן העולם הבא אבל לי נראה כי לא זאת המרגוע ולא בזאת יתהלל המתהלל כי אם בזאת יתהלל השכל וידוע בספרי פוסקים דיני תורה כגון האלפסי והמרדכי והרא"ש ודומיהם דזהו שורש ועיקר לתורתנו ואינם יוצאים כלל בלימוד גמרא פירוש תוספות דהא דתנא דבי אליהו וכו' כבר כתב רש"י שם כל השונה הלכות פירוש הלכות פסוקות ומ"ש רבינו תם כאן תלמוד בבלי בלול וכו' קאי אמ"ש רבינו לפני זה אלימוד תשע שעות ביום דכיון שיש לו פנאי גדול ילמוד בתלמוד אבל הנך בעלי בתים שאינם לומדים כי אם ג' או ד' שעות לא ילמדו בתלמוד לחוד כנ"ל

There is no reason for the Mishnah Berurah here to quote the Birchei Yosef's comment that it is good to learn mussar, because despite it being a good thing to learn mussar it is not part of the parameters of the obligation of daily Torah study.

Comment: There is a change adam regarding the importance of musar if someone can study only one thing

Comment: @kouty I assume you mean Chayei Adam Hilchos Yom Kippur Klal 143? Indeed, in the Sha'ar Hatziyun on the Mishnah Berurah under discussion he mentions the Chayei Adam.

Answer (score -1):

"Technically", **Mussar, unlike learning the Gemmorah, does not constitute a "pure" Limud Torah.** (*I know many confuse and call Limud Torah to all Torah related activities, that's why I said "technically"*)

1. There are two purposes in learning Torah: 1. To know how to observe it (הכי תמצי for keeping Mitzvos) 2. The purpose of learning per se as the way of clinging to G-d (לעסוק בדברי תורה  - "לולי תורתך שעשועי"). (In Derech Ha'Avodah it is explained as בחי' שמים וארץ - the heavenly Torah and the Earthy/practical Torah)
2. Mussar belong to the first purpose of knowing how to serve Hashem better, how to have right intentions, how to cultivate right beliefs etc. It has a very specific intention of implementing the study into one's life.

**Implications:**

As I answered elsewhere, this distinction applies in other areas:

- Women are obligated to learn the first incl Mussar but not the second
- Gentiles are allowed to learn the first but prohibited to learn in a second manner
- The first way does not obligate a Berachah as it is a part of the Mitzvah itself, e.g. learning Hilchos Hannukah is a part of lighting the candles. The second way obligates a Berachah.  (This is one of the explanations of the Gemmorah "שלא ברכו בתורה תחילה" as learning to observe does not obligate Benching).

---

*As I said, please don't comment on this, my approach is a theoretical outlook in the tradition of my Rabbi Z"L, this is not the mainstream explanation and is not consciously followed by most Poskim.*